# How to remove the Whitespace being created by Google translate Button at Top and Footer of WebPage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I have an HTML Page : https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/cytest.html

Just After I add Google Translate button to it, a whitespace occurs on the top and bottom of the page.

If I remove google translate all is correct.

Just Navigate into my webpage to see the issue.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On body tag, you have `position: relative`. Remove that and it will solve your problem

[image]

Comment: I could not find element.style in my code ? I checked my source code, but could not element.style.